# Trouble with drag events after Angular upgrade to 8. (using D3)

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I'm just in the middle of upgrading our app from Angular 6 to 8 (which includes updating many dependencies) and I've come across an issue with dragging d3 nodes. After my upgrading I am now presented with this error whenever trying to drag nodes:

```
breadcrumbs.js:64 TypeError: Cannot read property 'ctrlKey' of null
    at SVGRectElement.defaultFilter (drag.js:10)
    at SVGRectElement.mousedowned (drag.js:51)
    at SVGRectElement.<anonymous> (on.js:27)
    at SVGRectElement.sentryWrapped (helpers.js:74)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39679)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:465)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1603)
    at SVGRectElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone-evergreen.js:1629)
```

When I take a look at `drag.js` in chrome dev tools I get this:

```
import {dispatch} from "d3-dispatch";
import {event, customEvent, select, mouse, touch} from "d3-selection";
import nodrag, {yesdrag} from "./nodrag.js";
import noevent, {nopropagation} from "./noevent.js";
import constant from "./constant.js";
import DragEvent from "./event.js";

// Ignore right-click, since that should open the context menu.
function defaultFilter() {
  return !event.ctrlKey && !event.button;
}
...
```

If I breakpoint inside `defaultFilter()` and look at the `event` imported at the top of the file, it is an event object with the correct target and everything but the event object inside the function (`return !event.ctrlKey && !event.button`) is null.

Also, we use `this.d3.select(this.el.nativeElement).call(this.d3.drag().on('drag', onDrag))` in a directive to add the drag event listener to the nodes.

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated! If you need more info, I am happy to give more.

Comment: As part of your upgrade, are you also updating the version of d3? I'm curious if the d3 upgrade is what caused the change. Maybe try a quick null check on event? e.g. `return !event && !event.ctrlKey && !event.button;`

Comment: It stopped the error but I think the problem is that the event is null to begin with.

My package.json has gone from:
`"d3": "^5.9.2", "d3-ng2-service": "^1.15.0",`
to 
`"d3": "^5.12.0", "d3-ng2-service": "^2.0.0",`

Comment: Is it possible to recreate in StackBlitz? I just realized that drag.js is in the d3 source code. It feels like it's a `this` issue where d3 is using the local scope which has access to the event to see the event context. For your `onDrag` function is it possible to do something like `.on('drag', (e) => onDrag(e))`?